# Firebase Classes Not found

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pubspec.yaml

In my flutter project, I have added the firebase_core and firebase_messaging packages to pubspec.yaml but the import statement

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'
```

throws the error below:

> Target of URI doesn't exist:
> 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'.

This is a sections of my pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  provider: ^6.0.5
  get_it: ^7.6.0
  injectable: ^2.2.0
  dio: ^5.3.2
  retry: ^3.1.2
  
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.5
```

What could be the possible problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the IDE doesn't update to your latest package, so
`flutter pub clean,` then `flutter pub get`, close the IDE and re-Open it.

I the Issue still persisted consider Using : `flutter pub cache clean`

Comment: I have done that already

Comment: share you pubspec.yaml

Comment: I have editted the question to include the pubspec.yaml

Comment: try flutter pub cache clean

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly, thanks. But, I had to run `flutter pub get` on all my other projects

Comment: if it worked consider accepting my answer. flutter pub cache clean delete entire packages downloaded into ur PC